# $ is not defined in Laravel 5.6 projects with make:auth scaffolding and default app.js

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-mix

I have two separate Laravel 5.6 projects, and for some reason I am unable to use jQuery on either.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="masked">

    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="/js/app.js" defer>    </script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
                window.location = $(this).data("href");
            });

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

...

</body>
</html>
```

All of the resources are loading up fine according to the Network Inspector. I've tried moving the script block to the end of body, but that didn't help. I also tried invoking jQuery like this, to no avail:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).data("href");
    });

});
```

I checked app.js and it looks fine. I checked bootstrap.js and it looks fine.

**app.js**

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Next we will register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that
 * all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached. This is just
 * a simple convenience so we don't have to attach every token manually.
 */

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

// import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

// window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

// window.Echo = new Echo({
//     broadcaster: 'pusher',
//     key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
//     cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
//     encrypted: true
// });
```

Why is jQuery undefined whenever I try to use it?

**webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
let webpack = require('webpack');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Popper: 'popper.js'
        })
    ],
   });
```

Comment: You need to use the `ProvidePlugin` with `webpack` to expose jQuery in a global way to your application. Show us your `webpack.mix.js` file and we'll help you fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ProvidePlugin` that's shipped with `webpack` will expose factory variables globally to be used anywhere in your application. Since you're using `bootstrap 4`, the following configuration will work for you:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      Popper: 'popper.js' //not sure if this is necessary
    })
  ],
});
```

This assumes that you have defined `mix` in your `webpack.mix.js` file somewhere, like:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix')
```

The reason that this approach is necessary, even though you're including jQuery in your `js` file, is that webpack is aliasing all of the variables internally, so `jQuery` isn't available outside of your application scope. Using the `ProvidePlugin` ensures that the variables are available as their default name anywhere in your application code, regardless of in the bundle, or in a view.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, and simple explanation. Was this a recent change to Laravel? I've never had to mess with webpack.

Comment: @MichaelRodriguez Not that I'm aware of, it's been like this for at least a few releases.

Comment: Ok so I thought I could take it from here, but I still can't seem to get this to work. I've edited my question to show my webpack.mix.js after implementing your suggestion. Still getting the same error in console after running npm run production (dependencies are installed).

Comment: @MichaelRodriguez What happens if you log `$` in the javascript console in your browser?

Comment: Interesting development: i found that it works out of the box, without the changes to webpack, if I remove the “defer” attribute from the script element invoking app.js. So I guess that means the problem is actually that my jquery snippet was trying to use jquery before it had been fully loaded.

Comment: @MichaelRodriguez that would also be true, yes, you would still run into some other problems, but if you don't need this, you can remove the acceptance and down vote it!